# Counterexample of Egorov's Theorem in infinite limit function case

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Is there a simple example that shows [Egorov's theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q&f=false) fails when the domain $E$ is finite but the limit function $f$ is infinite in a set of positive measure? That is $m(E)<\infty$,  $f_k \to f$ a.e. on $E$ with $f_k$ finite but $f$ infinite in a set of positive measure.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Egoroff's Theorem does hold even if $f$ is not finite. By splitting the space into the parts where $f$ is finite and where it is infinity you can concentrate on the case when $f=\infty$ almost eveywhere. Thus, we have $f_n \to \infty$ almost everywhere. Now $\frac {f_n} {1+|f_n|} \to 1$ almost everywhere. Given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $F \subset E$ such that $m(F)<\epsilon$ and $\frac {f_n} {1+|f_n|} \to 1$ uniformly on $E\setminus F$ (by the standard form of the theorem). But this implies $f_n \to \infty$ uniformly on $E\setminus F$.

Comment: In the first paragraph of page 57, the book (refer to the link in my question) says $|f|<+\infty$ is needed, doesn't it?

Comment: @user398843 Well, in the book 'uniform convregence' does not include the concept of converging uniformly to $\infty$. That is the reason finiteness is needed there.