# Egorov theorem: counter example when the limit function is not finite

Tags: measure-theory

I want to find an example of a measure space $(X,\mathfrak X, \mu),$ $\mu(X)<\infty,$ a sequence $(f_n)$ of measurable functions whose values are finite and which converges almost everywhere to a infinite valued function $f$, but such that this convergence is not almost uniform.

I am well aware of the following question: [Counterexample of Egorov's Theorem in infinite limit function case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932663/counterexample-of-egorovs-theorem-in-infinite-limit-function-case) and if I did understand right, the given answer says that this problem is dependent on the definition of uniform convergence. I think that the book that I'm using, Bartle's Elements of Integration, does not consider uniform convergence to infinity; also, this question is actually an exercise in Bartle's book, which ask us to prove that $f_n= n \chi_{[0,1]} $ is such a sequence. But I'm not sure about the example given by the book, since $\mu(\mathbb R) = \infty$ and i'm not sure where $f_n$ converges when $x\in [0,1]$.

Any help or discussion is much appreciated.

Comment: if $x\notin [0,1]$ then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, and when $x \in [0,1]$ then $f_n(x)=n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, so $f(x)=\infty $ in this case